# How do I call window.setInterval correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing some code and I assume the code below will run the 'somefunction()' every 2 seconds. However, it only runs once. Why is this?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {window.setInterval(somefuntion(), 2000);});
```

Comment: What is the content of "somefunction()"? also it should be a function reference, not calling the function itself...

Comment: As @EranMedan said, you just need to reference the function. So instead of `somefunction()`, use only `somefunction`. Also, a JS error could be stopping the script, so you'll need to check if is that what is happening.

Comment: here's a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/tqzhZ/

Comment: that did the trick! sorry im new to jQuery!

Comment: @Liondancer JQuery isn't the problem. The `setInterval` function takes in arguments in a specific way. It's not a JQuery function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are not telling `setInterval()` to run the function `somefuntion()` every 2 seconds, you are calling `somefuntion()` and passing its return value as parameter to `setInterval()`.

Try again with `window.setInterval(somefunction, 2000);`.